# How mxgraph chart be panned on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, mxgraph

I have mxgraph application with default panning behavior (no settings from code). Chart can be moved in desktop browsers using right mouse.

On mobile browsers there is no right mouse button, so I cannot find a way to move (pan) mxgraph and only small part of chart is visible.

What do I need to set for mxgraph to allow scrolling/panning to see other parts of chart?

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to pan chart using setting for left mouse button. In this case on mobile screens it works fine.

```
graph.setPanning(true);
graph.panningHandler.useLeftButtonForPanning = true;
```